# How to compile just one chapter, with bibliography of citations in that chapter?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, chapters, include

I'd like to compile one chapter in a thesis, and include the bibliography, with only the citations found in that chapter.

I am using `\include` and `\includeonly` to get just the chapter I want, but it comes with the entire bibliography. If I edit the `aux` file to remove mention of all other chapters after running `pdflatex` once with the `includeonly`, then do `bibtex` and two more `pdflatex`, I get what I want. Is it possible to achieve the same without manually editing the aux file? My understanding is it includes all the other chapters for the sake of cross-references - is there a way to preserve that but still only end up with a bibliography of citations from the one chapter?

Note, I'm not looking to add a bibliography to each chapter, I'm just looking to be able to build a single chapter with the bibliography of its citations.

Comment: it appears that simply switching from bibtex to biblatex solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that simply switching from bibtex to biblatex solved the problem!